# What does entity framework .load(MergeOption) do?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to upgrade a large application which uses Entity Framework 4 to use Entity Framework 5.
I've discovered a function like this:

```
public FooModel(FooEntity foo)
{
    _foo = foo;
    _foo.bars.Load(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.OverwriteChanges);
}
```

Where `foo` and `bar` are generated entities, with `bar` having a foreign key to `foo`.

It seems EF5 no longer has the `.Load(MergeOption)` function, and I've never seen it before.
Does anyone know what it does, and what its equivalent is?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13178313/784908 suggests that `Load` is part of DbContext - but my entity container inherits from DbContext, and still isn't available

---

My best guess is that it is used for Eager loading of the foreign keys (which I need to do, the context is created and disposed of many times in a request, and there is no guarentee it will exist/attached when FooModel is used)

[Entity Framework - eager loading of related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8806684/784908) shows I should be using `.Include()`, but that function doesn't seem to be available on an actual entity (I think the term is 'materialized query'?)

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Load()` loads an `IQueryable` query from database into the memory - in fact, `Local` property of the relevant entity of your DbContext.

You can use this method with any IQueryable collection, not just the DbContext. Examples are as the following:

```
var q = db.Products.Include("Category").ToList();
q.Load(); // -> you can't!

// ------------

db.Products.Include("Category").Load(); // It's OK!

// This will NOT query the database, just looks in-memory data.
var p = db.Products.Local.Single(id); 

// ------------

var q = db.Products.Include("Category").ToList();
q.AsQueryable().Load(); // -> It's OK!

// This also will NOT query the database, just looks in-memory data.
var p = db.Products.Local.Single(id);
```

The load function is mainly used for 2 reasons:

1) Retrieving some parts of data from Db to memory and work with them:

```
db.Products.Include("Category").Where(p => p.CatId == 10).Load();
```

2) To be able to use Linq-to-Objects methods which L2E doesn't supports(like .ToString(), etc.) - as the Local property of DbContext entities are `ObservableCollection<T>` which implements `IEnumerable`, just as L2O objects:

```
db.Products.Include("Category").Where(p => p.CatId == 10).Load();
string subName = db.Products.Local.Find(id).SubString(0, 4);
```